# undefined local variable or method `nominations_data'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently unable to pass information from the cycles controller to  the cycle_nominees_table.html.erb using partials.

The data is defined in my controller show method. 
And the show method has information in the @nominations_data and @nominations_team_data.

Why cant my _cycles_nominations_table.html.erb access nominations_data thats being passed into the partial?

Ive been using this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for direction.

Code Below:

app/controllers/cycles_controller.rb

```
 def show
...

    @nominations_data = {}
    @nominations.each do |nomination|
      @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id] ||= {}
      @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominee] ||= nomination.for_user
      if user_is_admin
        @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominations] ||= []
        @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominations].push nomination
      end
      if user_is_admin_or_reviewer
        @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id][:count] ||= 0
        @nominations_data[nomination.for_user_id][:count] += 1
      end
    end
    @nominations_data = @nominations_data.sort_by { |_nid, nomination| nomination[:nominee].name }

    @nominations_team_data = {}
    @team_nominations.each do |nomination|
      @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id] ||= {}
      @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominee] ||= nomination.for_user
      if user_is_admin
        @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominations] ||= []
        @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id][:nominations].push nomination
      end
      if user_is_admin_or_reviewer
        @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id][:count] ||= 0
        @nominations_team_data[nomination.for_user_id][:count] += 1
      end
    end
    @nominations_team_data = @nominations_team_data.sort_by { |_nid, nomination| nomination[:nominee].name }

end
```

app/views/cycles/show.html.erb

```
          <div class="container-float-right-small" id="cycle-nominees-section">
            <h2 class="inline">Nominees for <%= @cycle.name %></h2>
            <h4 class="inline"> - (<%= @cycle.votes_per_reviewer %> votes allowed)</h4>
        <h5> Indivdual Nominees: </h5>
<!--        <%= render "cycles/cycle_nominees_table" %>-->
    <%= render partial: "cycles/cycle_nominees_table", locals: { nominations_data: @nominations_data } %>
        <h5> Team Nominees: </h5>
<!--        <%= render "cycles/cycle_nominees_table" %>-->
        <%= render partial: "cycles/cycle_nominees_table", locals: { nominations_data: @nominations_team_data } %>
          </div>
```

app/views/cycles/_cycle_nominees_table.html.erb

```
  <% if nominations_data.empty? %>
      <th class="center" colspan="4"><h3>There are no nominees <%= "for cycle '#{@cycle.name}'" if @cycle %></th>
    <% end %>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% nominations_data.each do |nid, data| %>
      <tr id='<%= "nominee-row-#{nid}" %>' class="nominee-row">
        <% if user_is_reviewer && @cycle.voting_open %>
          <td class="center">
            <% nomination_icon_class = "voted_for" if Vote.where(cycle_id: @cycle.id, by_user_id: current_user.id, for_user_id: data[:nominee].id).count > 0 %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check pointer <%= nomination_icon_class %>" id=<%= "vote_for_nominee_#{nid}" %> onclick="<%= "Vote.send_vote_data(this, #{data[:nominee].id}, #{@cycle.id})" %>"></span>
          </td>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: I don't see any references to `_cycles_nominations_table.html.erb`, do you mean `_cycle_nominees_table.html.erb`?

Comment: edited: it is _cycle_nominess_table.html.erb. this code renders without the passing of the nomination_data

Comment: Which use of the partial is causing the problem? Individual Nominees or Team Nominees?

Comment: either one, the issue is nominations_data is Nil in the cycle_nominees_table. But both: `@nominations_data` and `@nominations_team_data` have data present in them. if i change nominations_data to `@nominations_data` or `@nominations_team_data` it works as expect in  cycle_nominees_table

Comment: No, the error message says that there is no `nominations_data` local variable defined at all, if it was set but `nil` you'd get a NoMethodError on the `nominations.each` call. The error would suggest that you're saying `<%= render partial: "cycles/cycle_nominees_table" %>` somewhere (i.e. without the `locals:`).

Comment: ive tried this line as well: `<%= render "cycles/cycle_nominees_table", nominations_data: @nominations_team_data  %>` trying to access it with `local_assigns[:nominations_data]` and i get this error back `undefined method \`empty?' for nil:NilClass`. It seems whatever i pass to this table does not show in the table, is losing scope of these variables?

Comment: `local_assigns[:nominations_data]` being `nil` says that you're missing `locals:`. What makes you think that those `render partial: ...` calls are the problem?

Comment: I was under the assumption `<!--  <%= render partial: "cycles/cycle_nominees_table"-->` this line would be ignored, when in fact the error was complain about this old call, not the new call i was making (i ommited it from the original post)...

Comment: The ERB handler doesn't interpret HTML comments. If you need to comment-out some ERB then you'd say `<%#= render partial: ... %>`.